# ng zorro select not loading the options

Tags: angular, angular-forms, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

I am creating a website using Angular 7. I used ng zorro library everywhere in the application. I have a `nz-select` inside a `Form`. The `nz-select` is dynamically loaded by a model. The problem is we have two languages in the model object. But the default language given in the `ngModel` `[(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"` is the only one `nz-option` inside `nz-select`. I added two static `nz-option` to the `nz-select`. But only the default one is showing. So I just added another `nz-select` below the current one with two static `nz-option`. I did not give any default to that. So nothing populated and listed in the `nz-select`. `nz-select` is used in several places in the application like this. But this is the only one not working.

Note: If we change anything in the code and there will be an automatic reload happening. After the automatic reload the all `nz-option` will be there. But if we reload manually, only the default `nz-option` is showing if any.

My code snippet below.

```
       <nz-form-control>
            <nz-select
                id="preferredLanguage"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"
                name="preferredLanguage"
                (ngModelChange)="onValueUpdate('preferredLanguage', $event)"
                required>
                <nz-option
                    *ngFor="let languageType of languages"
                    nzValue="{{languageType.value}}"
                    nzLabel="{{languageType.label | translate}}">
                </nz-option>
            </nz-select>
        </nz-form-control>
```

.

```
export enum PreferredLanguage {
  GERMAN = 'GERMAN',
  ENGLISH = 'ENGLISH'
}
```

.

```
 selectedLanguage = Object.keys(PreferredLanguage)[0];
 languages = new Array<{ value: string; label: string }>();

ngOnInit(): void {
    Object.keys(PreferredLanguage).forEach(element => {
      this.languages.push({
        value: element,
        label: element
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: can you share your `.ts` code ?, this is not enough to see the issue

Comment: @KIRANKJ your code is work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1kgne

Comment: @HsuanLee The same code structure is working as desired in different pages. But here not working.

Comment: Have you try to console.log this value, or use `{{languages | json }}` check or any Debug?

Comment: @HsuanLee. it logging every item. But not populated in the list. I mentioned in above that, If I add a static option, it will not listed. It feels like a ghost effect.

Comment: @HsuanLee Got any idea?